# "Capturing" a program in C# WPF or Forms application and sending text commands to it

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio

So I don't have any code for this yet, as I want to know if the idea is feasible in a relatively simple way.

What I want to do basically, is make my own app, in C# either WPF or Forms, but I belive that should be irrelevant. What I want to do within that program is process some data I get from somewhere, and then output that data as a command to another program, that I did not "create" but is simply a window running on said PC. The thing is it's a commercial product, to which I obviously do not have direct access or source code,  but I want to "capture" it so that it stays within my window, but runs like it normally would. Something like this:

[image: very basic mockup]

What I basically want is to just make the window of the other program to stay inside mine as if it was some part of it.

Once that is done I only want to send it commands as if they were sent via keyboard. I do not want to change how it's running in any way.

I just have no idea where to start looking for this and what to even google for, a code example would be nice, but other then that I have quite some experience so documentation would probably do.

Comment: you could use sendkeys when you give the other application focus.  Other than that you will need to hook the program

Comment: Thanks I think that seems to be the right expression to look for, I didn't think of it before.

Comment: that is not an easy task, embedding the program in yours visually is already difficult. Sending keys to it might work, but what if there is some functionality that cannot be passed via the keys ? Many apps don't have key board shortcuts for all their commands. What if you want to make it process a file, are you going to make it show its own open file dialog after maybe you just showed yours ?

Comment: I only need and want text commands. Nothing else. It just has to be visually inside to have a sort of aesthetic feel to it.